# Database error-kohana framework

Tags: php, database, kohana

I am getting a a page not found error every time i connect to the database.
On the page of the database i have to login twice, but how can i solve this problem ?
Because i think the problem is that i have to login twice.

Comment: Without being able to see your page code, it's going to be all but impossible to help.  Could you post the applicable controller, model, and config files?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be throwing an exception, which is caught and handled by showing a *page not found* error?